# improveddown causing scrollbar flickering

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have used improveddropdown jquery plugin... my page has 10-20 dropdowns.. when the page loads the vertical scrollbars starts flickering.. it flickers because the improveddrodown jquery runs on dropdowns which takes some time... how to avoid this flickering of the scrollbar?

Comment: can u show a fiddle. create one in jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Try this, inside the improvedDropDown.js, replace the above code. I have add 2 lines, the first is hide the control until its populate, and then show it. Try to see if this solve your problem. I must say that I try to reproduce your problem but I fail to see any flickering.

```
this.each(function () {
    var thisElement = $(this);

    var wrapperControl = getWrapperElement(thisElement);

    // hide it
    wrapperControl.hide();

    thisElement.after(wrapperControl);

    var newImgElement = getImageElement(thisElement,iconPath);
    wrapperControl.append(newImgElement);

    var newTextElement = getTextElement(thisElement, newImgElement);
    wrapperControl.prepend(newTextElement); 

    var newListControl = getListElement(thisElement);
    wrapperControl.append(newListControl); 

    populateList(thisElement, newListControl,noMatchesText,noItemsText);

    if (document.activeElement == thisElement[0]) {
        //if replaced element had focus, move it to new control.
        newTextElement.focus().select(); 
    }

    if (debugMode != 1) { 
        thisElement.hide();                                                
    }

    // show it now
    wrapperControl.show();
 });
```